# Using LINQ with join and new object selection clauses causes exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, exception

I'm using a SQLite database with a table Activity(Id, Name), a table Craft(Id, Name) and a table linking the two ActivityCraft(Id, activity_ref, craft_ref, Paired).

The context used:

```
public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
public DbSet<Craft> Crafts { get; set; }
public DbSet<ActivityCraft> ActivityCrafts { get; set; }
```

I'm attempting to find the 'Paired' value for a particular Craft for all Activity entries in ActivityCraft.

The following query returns a list of Activities for the particular Craft as mentioned in the ActivityCraft table

```
var query2 = from a in context.Activities
             join ac in context.ActivityCrafts on a.Id equals ac.activity_ref
             where ac.craft_ref == SelectedCraftId
             select a;
```

However what is required is Activity.Name and ActivityCraft.Paired so I tried the following which fails

```
var query = from a in context.Activities
            join ac in context.ActivityCrafts on a.Id equals ac.activity_ref
            where ac.craft_ref == SelectedCraftId
            select new
            {
                xN = a.Name,
                xP = ac.Paired
            };
```

It appears that simply changing the selection clause results in an exception when the query executes.

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: The exception means there was an error in **static constructor** of the type, usually.

Comment: What does the `InnerException` property on the exception say?  That's probably going to give you the key to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering, but credit to both abatishchev and casperOne for the crib.

The problem is due to the use of BOOLEAN as a type for the Paired column. SQLite doesn't have a native BOOLEAN type, it uses INT - this leads to a problem when constructing even an anonymous type.

I solved the problem by changing the Db type to INTEGER and changing values to suit.

I did try to keep BOOLEAN in the Db, and use long as the equivalent c# type. This didn't work, I'm not certain why but it was still giving construction errors as if it was attempting to create type long from a 'true'/'false' string.  
Note: SQLite documentation says BOOLEAN are stored internally as INTEGER with value or 0 or 1